# Fortran Makefile with 2 executables

Tags: makefile, fortran, gnu-make, gfortran

I'm trying to compile 2 F90 files and to execute each one separately using a Makefile. The language used is fortran. I am not used to this so I need your help.
The first file is called HECESE_avec_modif.f90 and the second one is called hecese_seq.f90.
The makefile is below :

```
# Define dependance for suffix .FFREE
# -----------------------------------
.SUFFIXES: .exe .out .o .f .f90
#
# Compilation options for ifort
# ---------------------------------
# ---------------------------------
#FLAGS_fred = -free -O2 -traceback -mcmodel=large\
#        -check overflow -check bounds 
#FLAGS_fred = -FR -free -ftz -O3 -fPIC  
#F90_COMPILER = /opt/intel/bin/ifort  
#---------------------------------------------------------     
#
#  Compilation options for G95
# 
#FLAGS_fred = -C -O3 -ffree-form -ffree-line-length-huge -fzero
#FLAGS_fred = -O5 -ffree-form -ffree-line-length-huge -fzero
#F90_COMPILER = g95
#
#  Compilation options for GFortran
FLAGS_fred = -ffree-form -ffree-line-length-none -O3 #-march=native 
F90_COMPILER = gfortran -m64
F90_COMPILER7 = gfortran-7 -m64
#FLAGS_fred = -O3
#F90_COMPILER = gfortran
#FLAGS_CPPFOR = -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/x86_64/
#
#
#FLAGS_fred =  -free -O4
#
#
#       ***************************************************
#       ***************************************************
#       **                                               **
#       **    definition of file groups for F. Waymel    **
#       **                                               **
#       ***************************************************
#       ***************************************************
#

# 0.) group of all modules containing common variables
#    for multiblocs initialisation
#  ----------------------------------------------------
#
MAIN = HECESE_avec_modif.f90
MAIN2 = hecese_seq.f90

#
# Compilation of object files :
# -----------------------------
#
MAIN_OBJ     =$(MAIN:.f90=.o)
MAIN_OBJ2    =$(MAIN2:.f90=.o)
# Creation of executable:
# ---------------------------------
#
#DEST1         = ~/bin


EXEC  = hecesevfinale.out
EXEC2 = heceseseq.out

all : $(EXEC)  $(EXEC2) 

$(EXEC):$(MAIN_OBJ) 
    $(F90_COMPILER) -g $(FLAGS_fred) -o $(EXEC)  $(MAIN_OBJ)

$(EXEC2):$(MAIN_OBJ2) 
    $(F90_COMPILER) -g $(FLAGS_fred) -o $(EXEC2)  $(MAIN_OBJ2)

#


%.o : %.mod
.f90.o:
    $(F90_COMPILER) -g $(FLAGS_fred) -c  $<
#   $(F90_COMPILER) -g $(FLAGS_fred) -c  $<


%.o : %.mod
.f90.o:
    $(F90_COMPILER) -g $(FLAGS_fred) -c  $<
#   $(F90_COMPILER) -g $(FLAGS_fred) -c  $<


clean:
    rm -f *.o *.mod *.out
#depend .depend:
#   makedepf90 metas.f90 $(SOURCES90_fred1) $(SOURCES90_fred2) $(SOURCES90_mwl) $(SOURCES90_mwl2) > .depend   
#include .depend
```

I think that I made a mistake related to the second file.
The message I get when I execute this makefile is :

```
gfortran -m64 -g -ffree-form -ffree-line-length-none -O3  -o hecesevfinale.out  HECESE_avec_modif.o
make: *** No rule to make target 'hecese_seq.o', needed by 'heceseseq.out'.  Stop.
```

I have another problem when I try to execute `make clean`.
I get :

```
makefile:82: warning: overriding recipe for target '.f90.o'
makefile:76: warning: ignoring old recipe for target '.f90.o'
```

Can you help me, please ?

Comment: `MAIN_OBJ2    ==$(MAIN2:.f90=.o)`?

Comment: Notice the = in =hecese...

Comment: @francescalus I corrected it and still have the same problem. Even with `MAIN_OBJ2    =$(MAIN2:.f90=.o)`, I get the same error.

Comment: @VladimirF I still have the same problem even when I correct it. I edited my post. Normally, it is correct right now. But I still can't get a normal compilation.

Comment: Do you still get *exactly* the same error message? (Checking the obvious) You have saved the new version after you made the change? And you don't execute a makefile, you execute the make command (or related) which interprets the makefile and acts accordingly. Exactly how did you give the make command? Just "make"?

Comment: @IanBush yes I get the same error message. My OS is in French so the message I get is in French but in my question, I tried to translate it. Yes, just make (in the right place). the error is : `make: ***  Aucune règle pour fabriquer la cible « hecese_seq.o », nécessaire pour « heceseseq.out ». Arrêt.`

Comment: Excuse-moi, mais Il n'y a pas un = dans le dernier message. Also excuse me for my attempt at French!

Comment: You can use `LANG="C"` before `make` on the same line to get English error messages in amny operating systems. Maybe not in MS Windows.

Comment: But what you show is **NOT** exactly the same error message. Pmease update your queation with the new message.

Comment: @VladimirF I edited my question with the right error message. Thanks for the trick of `LANG="C"` !

Comment: @IanBush yes I edited my post. The error message is in English right now. Do you have any idea where the error comes from ? I think it comes from the second executable because with only one it works.

Comment: Do you have the file `hecese_seq.f90`?

Comment: @francescalus yes I have it.

Comment: @francescalus @VladimirF @IanBush I found the error. I forgot to copy the file `hecese_seq.f90` to the right folder. I tried to execute the make command without verifying if the second file exists. Thank you all for your help !

Comment: @francescalus I have another problem when I try to execute `make clean`. I get : `makefile:82: warning: overriding recipe for target '.f90.o'
makefile:76: warning: ignoring old recipe for target '.f90.o'`

Comment: You have `.f90.o:` twice in the makefile.

Comment: @francescalus Thank you it works perfectly now ! I thought I should write it twice because I have 2 files (my bad).